# is there an erro in the iText 7 jumpstart tutorials?

Tags: itext7

the example code says

```
table.setWidthPercent(100)
```

but the API docs for 7.1.0 say

```
table.useAllAvailableWidth()
```

Comment: The jump-start tutorials are outdated. This should be fixed. Then again, there are still people using 7.0.x, so if we fix the jumpstart tutorials, those people will say that they are wrong. Using the API docs is the most certain way to make sure that you're using the correct method.

Comment: Thanks Bruno... just getting to grips wth the new version, and your examples have always been the best place to start.

Comment: I think the new way to set a percent width is `table.SetWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));` (That gives you the opportunity to define other width percentages.)

Comment: table.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100))